# Drag and drop minimizing windows in Win 7/10 involving taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-10, taskbar, drag-and-drop

In Windows XP images from web browser can be dragged and dropped to desktop by holding file over taskbar while lmb is held down, then window minimizes itself and desktop shows up and you can drop it there.

I can't replicate this in Windows 7/10. I find this feature very useful. Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: Edited to be more clear.

Comment: Works fine here - Windows 7 64 bit, Firefox 46.0.1.

Comment: @DavidPostill it minimizes the current browser window when you drag an image from it to the taskbar?, I cannot get it to work in anything but XP.

Comment: @Moab - not exactly, but I dragged to the show desktop icon (right end of taskbar). Desktop shows, then I can drop image on desktop.

Comment: @DavidPostill oh your hovering over the peek bar in the right hand corner, this would answer the question, it still works but a bit different, you can answer if you want. In XP you could hover over any part of the taskbar.

Comment: @Moab Does it work in Windows 10 as well?

Comment: @DavidPostill Sure does. Be sure to up vote, as this is a great question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I find this feature very useful. Is there a way to enable it?

The behaviour is a little different on Windows versions newer than XP.

On Windows 7 and 10, you can:

1. Drag the image and hover over the the show desktop icon (by default it is located at the right hand end of the taskbar):

   Windows 7 Classic Theme

   <kbd>[image]</kbd>

   Windows 7 Aero Theme

   <kbd>[image]</kbd>

   Windows 10 Aero Theme

   <kbd>[image]</kbd>

2. The desktop will be displayed and you can drop the image.

Comment: Any ideas on how to make this work in Win 10 Tablet Mode? (I realize it wasn't part of the question).

Comment: @Fuhrmanator No idea. I don't have a tablet ...